# Java Setup on Scientific Linux showing two diffent versions

Tags: java, linux, selinux

Java Setup on Scientific Linux showing two diffent versions.

I am trying to get java setup right on Scientific Linux.

If I do a **javac -version** I get the following: **java_1.7.0_10** which is the version that I really want to be using.

But if I do a **java -version** I get the following:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (rhel-1.50.1.11.5.el6_3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)**
```

Which is not the version I would like to run with... Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue.. thanks

Comment: $ which java  ; which javac

Comment: Are you trying to find the Oracle JRE? Is that what you are asking? Is that not the most recent OpenJDK version>?

Comment: its I am trying to use java 7.  If I do which java I get /usr/bin/java.  If I do which javac I get /usr/bin/javac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this to choose java alternative if you have already installed.

```
  /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

Comment: I did enter the comment (/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java) but only seeing openjdk?

Comment: then try to install it to alternatives. /usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jre1.7.0/bin/java 2

Comment: change values to match with your paths otherwise keep as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your $PATH enviroment-variable.

Type `which javac` to see where the javac-binary is located.

For example:

```
which javac -> /usr/local/bin/javac
```

then execute:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
```

Could you post please the output from:

`which java && which javac`

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

Comment: I did a which java and a which javac and both goto /usr/bin

Comment: Two different versions in the same directory? strange..
I recommend to re-install the jdk or to install it new and let update-alternatives (as root) do the job.

Comment: how do I install a RPM with sudo only

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try: rpm -ivh filename

Comment: I did a reinstall of the JRE and the JDK of 7u10 but 1.6.0_24 is still only showing up

Comment: Could you please post the output from "update-alternatives --list java" ?